# How to set value automatically on input field in form by getting data from API in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, api

My task is that getting data from database (API) and set that value in input form automatically without page refresh.

I am able to get data from database through API and able to set value into input form. It works when I refresh the page. but when a new row has recorded in database it is not able to set the value automatically but works with new value after reloading the page again.

```js
$.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-volume-data", function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#volume_data').val(data.volume_data);
  });
```

```html
   
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="volume_data"> Data</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="volume_data" id="volume_data" placeholder="Enter Data">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: After set the new value, you need to call that api again

Comment: Remove the script tags in your stack snippet they are no javascript code! (see error the message when you click "*Run code snippet*")

Comment: I think you need to persist the data in the browser data model then you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a websocket to update in real time.
But for short term solution, you can send the request to the API again in a few moments.

```
function getData() {
  $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-volume-data", function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#volume_data').val(data.volume_data);
  });
}
getData(); // first call

setInterval(getData(),3000); // call again per 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

A frontend script cannot really tell when data was changed at the backend. The only way of getting new data is getting it in a regular interval:

```js
function getData() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin", function (d) { 
    $('#volume_data').text(d.datetime);
  });
}
getData(); // first call
setInterval(getData,3000); // call again every 3 seconds
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Current time in central Europe is <span id="volume_data"></span>.</p>
```

In the above snippet I used the (highly frequented) world clock JSON-API: https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin. The data returned from there is json and `$.getJSON()` will automatically do the parsing after the string has been received.